A module with arbitrarily large finite linearly independent subsets but without an infinite linearly independent subset
Does there exist an example of a commutative ring with unity $R$ and an $R$-module $M$ such that:

If $L \subseteq M$ is linearly independent, $|L| < \infty$.

For any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a linearly independent $L \subseteq M$ with $|L| \geq N$.


Equivalently, we can require:

There is no injection $R^{(I)} \hookrightarrow M$ for any infinite $I$

For any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n \geq N$ and an injection $R^n \hookrightarrow M$


Stated more generally, considering the collection of cardinalities of the linearly independent subsets, does there exist an example where this collection does not attain its supremum?
Here are the cases which I've looked at which don't yield such an example:
If $R$ is a field, such an example cannot occur. If there are arbitrarily large linearly independent subsets, the dimension must be at least $|\mathbb{N}|$, meaning that there exists an infinite linearly independent subset, a contradiction.
If $M$ is finitely generated, such an example cannot occur, since there cannot be any infinite linearly independent set. See Infinite linear independent family in a finitely generated $A$-module .

Which axiomatic theory of sets are you assuming?

@DavidA.Craven ZFC

Is there a subtlety when doing the standard Zorn's lemma argument, like proving that every vector space has a basis?

@DavidA.Craven Yes, the problem is that we don't assume that all finite subsets are linearly independent. We only assume that there are arbitrarily large finite linearly independent subsets.

Sure, not all finite subsets are linearly independent, that's also true for vector spaces. But you would let $X$ denote the set of all linearly independent subsets of $M$, not all finite subsets. $X$ is obviously a poset. Then the upper bound of a chain is the union of the chain, so ZL applies.

@DavidA.Craven I don't see how to show that the maximal elements of $X$ are infinite.

So if $R$ is a domain you are now done, because all maximal linearly independent subsets have the same cardinality. This isn't true in general, and I'm wondering if some horrific $R$ like the direct sum of all $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ acting on an $\mathbb N$-generated module in some terrible way might do what you want, not have an infinite linearly independent set.

@DavidA.Craven I just found https://mathoverflow.net/q/30066/155881 , where some large list of conditions for all maximal linearly independent subsets to have the same cardinality is exhibited. It seems like some counterexample from there could lead to a counterexample here.

Here's the kind of thing that will have weird properties. Think of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb Z$ labelled by $\mathbb N$ acting on itself by standard multiplication, plus the $i$th copy moves everything down $i$ places on the module, or something like this. Points in the first $n$ copies of $\mathbb Z$ look reasonable because most of the ring annihilates it, but as you try to increase the size of the linearly independent set you must leave the first $n$ copies, and then the rest of the module acts to push this new element into a linear combination.

I'm not saying this works, I'm saying once you leave the realm of finitely generated you can do really ridiculous things.

@David Unfortunately I don't understand your idea. Why ring do you take? Which module?

@Smiley1000 do I understand your question correctly, that you would like to have an example of a module $M$ over a commutative unital ring $R$ such that $R^n$ embedds into $M$ for each $n\geq 1$, but the free module $R^{(\mathbb{N})}$ of rank $\mathbb{N}$,  does not?

This is indeed equivalent to the question.

@ChristianLomp Exactly

@ChristianLomp I've added your reformulation to the question.
